# Eclipse throws error Can't find variable: angular

Tags: referenceerror

I am new to the eclipse environment and have been working on Microsoft VS. Currently I have to work on the angularjs project on Eclipse. When I try to add new module in the application the eclipse gives me the error

```
!JavaScript ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular on line 1 for http://localhost:17594/Login/MyApp.Login.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular on line 1 for http://localhost:17594/Camera/MyApp.Camera.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular on line 1 for http://localhost:17594/Chart/MyApp.GoogleChart.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular on line 1 for http://localhost:17594/Register/MyApp.Register.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Is there anything I am Missing.

Following is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="MyApp">
       <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
         <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="/Login/MyApp.Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Camera/MyApp.Camera.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Chart/MyApp.Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Chart/MyApp.GoogleChart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Register/MyApp.Register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/ionic.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything wrong in cordova.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ionic.bundle has to be first, before cordova.js?
My code looks like:

```
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="lib/toaster/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- ionic/angularjs js --> 
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- angular touch --> 
<script src="lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) --> 
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks Tana. How come I never thought of this.